# Variable datasets in Excel when recording Macro. VBA

Tags: excel, select, multiple-columns, vba

I am recording a macro in order to make a simple process I have to go trough very often a bit more simple. I have no problem as it is extremely simple but in the stage I have three columns. Let's call them Green, Amber and Red, and I want to create just one by putting one on top of the other one giving a (up-down) Red, Amber and Green column as a result.

When the data set changes and these columns change their size (more or less rows) the macro cuts those columns based on the absolute references it took when the macro was recorded.

I want that selection (selection of red amber and green as single columns to be pasted onto a single one) be 'dynamic' and change as the data set does.

[image]

The way I select the individual columns is like this.

```
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveCell.Range("A1:B7").Select
Selection.Cut
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -5).Range("A1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9).Range("A1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveCell.Range("A1:B8").Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(0, -9).Range("A1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
```

In this case I was trying to use relative references just in case magic happened automatically. I do not know any VBA programming so that is why I use macros.

I would go into more detail but I think whoever knows a bit about VBA will know how to fix this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you can use CurrentRegion which will automatically resize to take in all contiguous rows and columns.

```
Sub x()

Range("A:B").ClearContents

Range("N1").CurrentRegion.Copy Range("A1")
'alternative to above if CurrentRegion not applicable
'Range("N1",range("N" & rows.count).end(xlup)).resize(,2).Copy Range("A1")
Range("J1").CurrentRegion.Copy Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
Range("F1").CurrentRegion.Copy Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)

End Sub
```